# Arrays con llave y valor

Tags: php, php7

Hoy en día me encuentro aprendiendo programación php y estoy incursionando con los arreglos, haciendo un ejercicio donde se me pide que tengo que crear un array y a ese array pasarle claves y valores y luego mostrarlos. Hasta el momento he elaborado este código, pero no entiendo muy bien cómo pudiese pasar un clave y un valor con el método `array_push` a un `array`.

Adjunto mi bloque de código

```
// Crear una función la cual agregue un array con su respectiva clave y valor

function vehicle_sale ($aa,$ab,$ac,$ad){
    
    $vehicle = [];
    array_push($vehicle,$aa,$ab,$ac,$ad);

    foreach($vehicle as $vehiculo => $cantidad){

        echo "Los vehiculos son los siguientes: $vehiculo y la cantidad de venta dde este vehiculo es $cantidad <br>";
    }

};

vehicle_sale('toyota','chevrolet','honda','wolsvangen');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uno de los problemas que tienes es que no tienes claro tu estructura de datos (el array) donde va a almacenarse la información.

Por otro lado, necesitas 2 funciones, una para registrar las ventas y otra para desplegar el resultado.

En esta propuesta, los datos se van acumulando en el array `$vehicles`. En la función `vehicle_sale()` se van insertando en el array, si el valor existe, la cantidad se suma a la existente. Ver [operador ??](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

Podrás notar que el array se está [pasando como referencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.references.pass.php) `&array`, lo cual conecta `$vehicles` con `$array` y así no hay que retornar. Sin embargo si no quieres trabajar así, puedes usar `return $array;`

Finalmente en la función `display_sales()` se muestran las ventas de todos los vehículos, o de uno en particular si lo especificas en la función.

```php
<?php
function vehicle_sale(&$array, $vehiculo, $cant){
    $array[$vehiculo] = ($array[$vehiculo] ?? 0) + $cant;
}

function display_sales($array, $vehiculo='all') {
    if($vehiculo == 'all') { // Todas las ventas
        foreach($array as $v=>$cant) {
            echo "$v ---> $cant" . PHP_EOL;
        }
    } elseif(array_key_exists($vehiculo, $array)) { // Una categoría
        echo "$vehiculo ---> $array[$vehiculo]" . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        echo "Error, vehiculo no encontrado" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$vehicles = [];

vehicle_sale($vehicles, 'toyota', 6);
vehicle_sale($vehicles, 'toyota', 4);
vehicle_sale($vehicles, 'chevrolet', 3);
vehicle_sale($vehicles, 'honda', 5);

display_sales($vehicles); // Todos los resultados
// toyota ---> 10
// chevrolet ---> 3
// honda ---> 5

display_sales($vehicles, 'honda');
// honda ---> 5

display_sales($vehicles, 'mazda');
// Error, vehiculo no encontrado
```

Comment: Gracias men, de verdad que ha sido de ayuda y así puedo ver mis errores y como puedo estructurarlo mejor

Answer (score 0):

Debes declarar primero el arreglo (array) y luego pasarle las propiedades o valores por ejemplo:

```
$vehicle = array();
$vehicle['marca'] = "toyota";
```

Luego con el array_push puedes meter ese vehiculo en el listado de vehiculos:

```
$vehiculos = [];
array_push($vehiculos, $vehicle);
```

Ya solo te quedaría recorrerlo con el Foreach.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.